# Error in Entity framework code first

Tags: entity-framework-5, code-first

Not sure why I am getting this error. It is a practice code so I learn the Entity Framework Code first approach.

I have the following in the web.config

```
<add name="CompanyDBContext"
     connectionString="server=.; database=CompanyDB;integrated security=true;"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
<connectionStrings>
```

and the following class

```
public class CompanyDBContext: DbContext
{

    public  DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

}
```

The error is:

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The Connection string format is wrong. The correct is:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="CompanyDBContext"
         connectionString="server=.; database=CompanyDB;integrated security=true;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```